# Updating PHP CMS admin erases image

Tags: php, php-8

I was wondering if I could please have some help with a PHP issue I'm having?
I'm a beginner and I've been working on making a basic CMS as a personal project to build my skills with.
It's all working so far, but on the admin page which updates the site, I'm having a problem with the updating part.
The page is populated by DB information, and it is updating when I choose to submit the update form. But if I only alter the text and don't re-select an image, or update the form without choosing a new image, the form sends an empty string to the database which erases the image that was there.

Here is the original code for the page:

```
<?php include("../core/db.php"); ?>
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page=$_GET['page'];
} else {
    $page="home";
}
?>

<?php
////Select from DB query
$query="(SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_title='{$page}')";
$get_page_query=mysqli_query($connection,$query);

if(!$get_page_query){
    die("Get page query problem" . mysqli_error($connection));
}

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_page_query)){
$page_title=$page;
$page_content=$row['page_content'];
$page_image=$row['page_image'];
}
?>

<!----Navigation---->
<table border="1">
<tr height="50">
    <td colspan="2"><a href="admin.php?page=home">Home</a> | <a href="admin.php?page=about_us">About us</a> | <a href="admin.php?page=about_our_style">About our style</a> | <a href="admin.php?page=fees">Fees</a> | <a href="admin.php?page=time_table">Time table</a> | <a href="admin.php?page=gallery">Gallery</a> | <a href="admin.php?page=contact">Contact</a></td>        
</tr>
</table>

<!----Update form---->
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>Page Image<br/>
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="image"></p>

<img src="../images/<?php echo $page_image; ?>" width="300">


<p>Page Content<br/>
<textarea name="page_content" type="text" rows="10" cols="100"><?php echo $page_content; ?></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="update" value="update"/></p>
</form>


<?php
////Update query
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    echo "Update posted";

    $page_content=$_POST['page_content'];
    
    $page_image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $page_image_tmp=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        
    move_uploaded_file($page_image_tmp, "../images/$page_image");


    $query="UPDATE pages SET page_image='{$page_image}', page_content='{$page_content}' WHERE page_title='{$page}'";
    $update_page_query=mysqli_query($connection,$query); 
    
    if(!$update_page_query){
    die("Update query problem" . mysqli_error($connection));    
    }
header("location:admin.php?page={$page}");
}
?>



I've spent a few hours on this but I can't work out how to fix it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for any help.
```

I've tried writing an if statement to fix it but it doesn't do anything at all:

```
    if(empty($_FILES['image']['name'])){
        $page_image=$row['page_image'];
    } else {    
    $page_image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $page_image_tmp=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        
    move_uploaded_file($page_image_tmp, "../images/$page_image");
    }
```

Comment: Change the update query to suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

First, only upload the file if one has been provided. The below code uses count() to check if a file was supplied:

```
if(count($_FILES) > 0) {
    $page_image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $page_image_tmp=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    
    move_uploaded_file($page_image_tmp, "../images/$page_image");
}
```

Second, you need to change the SQL query depending on if an image has been supplied:

```
// Set the query without a page image
$query="UPDATE pages SET page_content='{$page_content}' WHERE page_title='{$page}'";

// Set $query to include the page_image if an image was supplied    
if(count($_FILES) > 0) {
    $query="UPDATE pages SET page_image='{$page_image}', page_content='{$page_content}' WHERE page_title='{$page}'";
}

// Now run the query to update the database entry
$update_page_query=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
```

The above code will then:

- Only attempt to upload an image file if one was supplied
- Only update the page_image if an image was supplied